# Php Session user not working

Tags: php, arrays, session

First of all, I do use `session_start()` at the beginning of the page.

This is a different session problem, my login code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha']; //password

$user = new User();
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setSenha($senha);
$dao = new UserDao();
$login = $dao->login($user);

if($login != false) 
{
    $arrayL = $login->toArray();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $arrayL;
}
```

The problem is, the `$_SESSION['user']` is not working, not passing the information to the others pages.

To check if the session is working I tried this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ar']))
{
    $ar = array();
    $_SESSION['ar'] = $ar;    
}
else
{
    $ar = $_SESSION['ar'];
    $ar[] = "mais1";
    $_SESSION['ar'] = $ar;
}
```

this one runs everytime the page loads, and its working, the `$ar` array is growing normally.
But to make the things a lot weird,

I did add this code to the login script, to check if is adding to the `$ar` array, just for testing:

```
$arrayL = $login->toArray();
$_SESSION['user'] = $arrayL;
$ar = $_SESSION['ar'];
$ar[] = $arrayL;
$_SESSION['ar'] = $ar;
```

At the start and at the end of the page I set a `var_dump($_SESSION);`
And for my surprise when I do login, it shows the `$_SESSION['user]` and the `$ar` array with the users details. But when I reload the page, its gone, the `$ar` array stays there normally but without the `$user` information, and the `$_SESSION['user']` is completely gone.

What is going on?

Comment: You should use [session_start()](http://www.php.net/session_start)

Comment: @u_mulder is working normally as i said. session_start() is at the begining of the page, and keep the $ar array information, but not when i add the user information to the $ar array, and not the $_SESSION['user']

Comment: You should have `session_start()` at the top of _every_ page that uses `$_SESSION`

Comment: @MikeW indeed, in fact i do have. as i said, the $ar array at $_SESSION['ar'] is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['ar']))
    {
        $ar = array();
        $_SESSION['ar'] = $ar;

    }
else
    {
        $ar = $_SESSION['ar'];
        $ar[] = "mais1";
        $_SESSION['ar'] = $ar;
    }
```

so if the session "ar" is not set,   set session "ar" to $ar.  $ar is array consisting of "mais1".   when you do this $_SESSION['ar']['user'] is no longer there.

Comment: no, as i posted: $arrayL = $login->toArray();
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $arrayL;
                    $ar = $_SESSION['ar'];
                    $ar[] = $arrayL; so is not adding ['user] to $_SESSION['ar] is just incrementing, intead of "mais1" the users information

Comment: the same $arrayL containing the users information is being add to the $_SESSION['user'] and the $ar array.